# How to get the captured image from the camera app directly and upload to a web page

Tags: android, html, file-upload, camera

I have a question to save photo using android camera app. I made HTML5 file with an input element like :

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" />
```

this way i'm able to capture photo, display the captured photo after camera app and photo is returned directly to the html object when i hit the save button below the photo. 
When i try to open this page inside a webview, i saw that i have to do some tricks. So far so good. I'm able to open the camera and capture a photo.
Here is my question:
How can i display the last photo and save it to the html object like HTML5 does. I couldn't find a way to display the last photo. HTML5 does this easily but i'm stuck in the native version. Thanks for any help... (By the way, i use eclipse and galaxy s3 for testing the native app.)

Here is my code to open the camera app.

Activity Code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setType("image/*");       

FileUploadTest.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), 
    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that no one is interested in this question. Anyway i found the solution and wanted to share for anyone who is interested.

- don't forget to call the "super" of the method.
- don't forget to call "onReceiveValue" in each case. If you don't call it, your app's gonna crash

> ```
> @Override
>   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
>           Intent intent) {
>       try {
>           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
>
>           if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
>               mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(intent == null ? this.fileUri
>                       : intent.getData());
>           else
>               mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           Log.e("Error9", e.getLocalizedMessage());
>           mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
>       } finally {
>           mUploadMessage = null;
>       }
>   }
> ```